# How to add <br> tag after <img> tag?

Tags: php

I want to add `<br>` tag after `<img>` tag, my code:

```
$string = "< div> < img src="http://example.com/a.jpg"> < /div>";
$pattern = '/< img*+>+/i';
$replacement = '${1}'.'< br>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you absolutely need the `<br>` tag added?

You could do it using CSS instead:

```
img { display:block; margin-bottom:10px; }
```

If you only wanted to affect images within a certain section, you could limit it using:

```
.article img { display:block; margin-bottom:10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are trying to use `<br />` when some CSS would be better.

However, if you do intend to add a `br` after every `img` element, I would strongly suggest you skip messing around with the regex and use a DOM parser.